# Develop list within List in Android

Tags: android

I am getting a response from xml which is dynamic in nature .
After parsing the xml , I able to generate a tree view. 
Now , **I want to convert the tree view structure to a List view which will have multiple List(list within list & so on) depending on the depth of the xml.**

I am aware of the **ExpandableListActivity** which provide a two-levels of data.

In my case , **it can be more than two levels of data rather it should be dynamic in nature**.

I need any sample code to **implement the dynamic List i.e a List within another List & so on.**

Kindly help

Chiranjib

Comment: Isn't the tree view exactly what you want (variable, dynamic levels of nesting, each element can contain more elements)? What do you want to do with your "Lists withing List", that the tree view cannot do? (If you could say which class implements the tree view, that would help too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not display a list in a list. But you can switch between views. Clicking on a list item you can open a new view that contains the other list-layout. Or you can open a dialog that shows the elements of the second list. But the solution depends on what you want to achieve which is not really clear in your description.